# What to do when the OP comments his question with "Thanks I solved it"?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, unanswered-questions

I came accross this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578639/cannot-auto-configure-pydev-in-eclipse). The question hasn't received any answer and only one potentially helpful comment. Yet, the OP managed to find a solution on his own and commented his question with "Thanks I solved it".

This scenario reminded me a lot of a programming forum, where users don't have the motivation to leave their solution. By experience, and I think we all experienced this, stumbling upon this kind of question/answer when you have the exact same problem is very frustrating.

I did some research and found:

- [What do I do with my unanswered questions once I solve it by myself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255489/what-do-i-do-with-my-unanswered-questions-once-i-solve-it-by-myself)
- [Asked question, solved question, didn't accept/post answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290311/asked-question-solved-question-didnt-accept-post-answer)

But I still don't know what to do in this case. Here are two options:

1. Ask the user to answer his own question.
2. Downvote or maybe flag his question (IMHO, this is not a good quality question).

Arguments for the first option:

- An answered question fits more the essence of SE rather than a deleted/forgotten unanswered question.
- The question received one upvote, thus someone found it useful. This question deserves an answer.

Arguments for the second option:

- The question is poor; we have no information on the platform of the user (OS, Eclipse Python or pip version...)
- Chances are low that the asker will come back to provide a good quality answer describing what he tried, what worked, etc.

Leaving this question as it is is not worth considering; as I said, this frustrates me.

What would be the proper behaviour to adopt in this kind of situation?

Comment: This is my first participation here on MSO, do not hesitate to give me any feedback on this question and how I can improve it/future questions.

Comment: See the duplicate; when a new user thanks you like that you can give them a gentle note to show how accepting works. I personally use: *Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)*

Comment: @MartijnPieters the question has not received an answer; OP commented on the question that they solved it themselves (with help of the comments, probably). Thus the duplicate is invalid. DrHaze, regarding the question, IMO it should just be closed as it does not contain enough info to reproduce the problem. It's just "I did something and something else broke", with OP now saying "oh, it un-broke again" - there's nothing of value lost if the question is closed and eventually auto-deleted.

Comment: @l4mpi: oops, my mistake.

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that **can no longer be reproduced** or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."

Comment: @MartijnPieters np for this mistake, you'll still have my vote for the mods election ;-)  Thank you l4mpi and MichaelT for these clues, flagging this question was my original thought.

Comment: If the question doesn't need to be closed (or a solution might benefit others), you can leave a comment suggesting a self-answer. (I left one on the post being discussed, just in case the answer might help others in the future, in case someone needs an example of how to do so.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would vote to close it as *"a problem that can no longer be reproduced"*. It will likely be deleted eventually. The OP could delete it themselves (I think) since it has no answers. For users that can't close vote, yes, you could flag it.

If the OP doesn't want to answer it, then it's not useful and there's no point in keeping it around.

Judging by the text of the question, it was not really answerable in the first place, unless this is a well-known error.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it could be closed since the OP won't answer it, but I don't think it should always be removed.

The comments made might give a little help to some people with the same issue. And, in the last case, they could try to contact the OP in some other way to help them to solve the problem.