# Housekeeping my own self-answered questions

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

Over the past few weeks I've posted three questions that I've ended up answering myself.  Having read the advice in this question about ["What do I do with my unanswered questions once I solve it by myself?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255489/3581917), in particular the second answer, I was wondering what metrics to use to decide when to delete the questions?

I spent several days searching for the answers, experimenting, interpreting documentation, examining MAP files, running tests, and so forth, and it pains me to delete them if someone may find them useful at some time in the future.  (If I'd posted a few lines of source with a question about how to copy a string from an array of structs, I'd have had three answers in ten minutes, none of which would have been read again.)

It would appear that the subjects of my questions have a very small number of followers (possibly just me).  Would this make the rare solutions gems worth treasuring by the few?  Or would it mean they are less valuable because they don't help many people?

*Note*

I don't want to invoke the meta-effect, so no links to the questions here, but for background information they pertained to using GCC linker scripts to organise C variables and an interpretation of a couple of objects in the CANopen communication specification.  Neither of which has a particularly broad audience (apparently).

Comment: I think it might be hard to say something about the popularity of your questions after just a few weeks. The most useful Q/A's that I have encountered on this site were sometimes over a year old.

Comment: @LisaMM It was gaining the 'Tumbleweed' badge that made me wonder, and having to confirm the 'are you sure you want to answer your own question' prompt (again) a few days later that prompted me to ask.

Comment: Just imagine the surprise for someone who *does* need a solution.

Comment: @nwhaught, it's not clear that the OP did not invoke the effect (although they did try not to). I myself have had an unusual number of upvotes on my posts after a post with no links in it, I can only assume that people looked up my profile.

Comment: "*it pains me to delete them if someone may find them useful at some time in the future*" - well if they are (or might be) useful then there is absolutely no reason to delete them in the first place!

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Popularity is not/should not be any criterion in the decision to remove questions. If the question is good and well phrased and **even has a quality answer**, by all means I beg you in the name of Cthulhu **keep it**.

Maybe there'll be only one more person ever to find that question useful, but even just that one person will be very thankful. You've already done the work, let others benefit from it, however few of them may come.

Comment: +1 for the second paragraph.  I've gotten a few up votes for obscure very low view count questions years after they've been posted.

Comment: Yes, far better than a good solution to an obscure problem, than yet another 'why does this regex not work properly' :)

Comment: Heck, the "one more person" might even be the OP again after they've forgotten the answer. I've googled, landed on my own question, and re-learned from the answer before. Maybe that's just me, though.

Comment: @Frank Oh, definitely happened to me!

Comment: @Frank [More evidence it's not just you](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8725274#8725274)

Comment: Popular questions are usually easy to find. It's the unpopular, yet good ones that end up saving somebody life

Comment: Agreed, my most viewed question as far as I'm aware of also happens to be the one with the fewest votes. And indeed, even if it would have one view, that one person might be eternally thankful for a lot of time saved, but just happen to not have an account here.

Comment: Cthulhu fhtagn!

Comment: @Frank It's not just you. Once I voted to close a question as a duplicate of something the same user had asked years before. (Apparently they didn't google.)