# Would it be an error to delete directly my question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

About [questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402897/where-can-i-select-my-personal-plugins-in-gimp): would it be a waste to erase them directly after noticing my pitiful mistake?

This isn't the first time it happens to me, but the most clear example ever. I convince myself "you researched, tried, failed, now you are stack and noone has asked this before". Then I make the question. Some time after I keep thinking, reviewing what I have done and trying things... In this case, I found the answer by myself... and it was an epic (to not say pathetic) failure... I was sure that I did something that was needed, to realize **after posting the question** that I didn't at all.

So now I think "it doesn't seem useful for anyone else"... but I might be wrong, so maybe it is a bad idea deleting it directly"... Possible actions that I have in mind:

- Would it be better to let it stay there until some moderator finds it casually and decide what to do with it?
- Should I flag it directly for moderator review? Doesn't seem a good idea to make them bother about such kind of issues...
- Try to edit it so it would be more useful for everyone... this one doesn't seem to have that potential...

Comment: Similar to (duplicate of?) this [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255489/what-do-i-do-with-my-unanswered-questions-once-i-solve-it-by-myself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would anyone else ever have the same problem, be able to find your question, and have their problem solved as a result?

If yes, leave it there.  If any one of those things wouldn't happen, delete it.

> Would it be better to let it stay there until some moderator finds it casually and decide what to do with it?

No.  If you know that it's not useful, remove it yourself.

> Should I flag it directly for moderator review? Doesn't seem a good idea to make them bother about such kind of issues...

You're right, it's not a good idea.

> Try to edit it so it would be more useful for everyone... this one doesn't seem to have that potential...

If you can edit the question or your answer such that the answer to, "Would anyone else ever have the same problem, be able to find your question, and have their problem solved as a result?" is "yes", then you should absolutely edit it.

Comment: Thanks to you I've got my mind better set about how to take care of my own question's affairs... well, having in mind "someone else could make the same kind of slip while proceeding"... I'll leave it there just in case, and review it tomorrow... Ideas will get refreshed after I sleep some...

Comment: @SebasSBM Keep in mind that you need to consider each step.  Could someone else have this same problem? If yes, would they be able to find your question?  (Are there generic search terms that would plausibly be searched for when someone has this problem that would actually lead to your question?)  And of course, is the solution that works for you one that would help others with the same problem?