# Should I accept the only answer (which I could not understand) after finding my answer elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, answers

A very good person tried to help me but unfortunately I could not understand his answer. Maybe because I have a bad background on that specific subject or he just wrote a bad answer. This was the only answer I got so far and he did try to help me again in the comments.

Not voting shows disrespect and surely he want me to accept the answer.

***I did find my answer from another source***

What is the best approach to handle this?

Comment: If you are talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616472/what-exactly-does-the-provide-function-get-as-parameters the answer look very good and at least related to the question (speaking from general  DI point of view), so please don't delete the post. There is good chance that you want to read on DI frameworks in general before deciding fate of the answer (definitely you *should not* accept something that did not help you as discussed in answers - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317735/477420)

Comment: [What do I do with my unanswered questions once I solve it by myself?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255489/what-do-i-do-with-my-unanswered-questions-once-i-solve-it-by-myself)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the best approach to handle this?

Accepting an answer isn't mandatory and totally left on your behalf deciding it was the most helpful one for you.

If it wasn't actually helpful for you, because it has gone beyond your horizon, you should ask for clarification in comments, or add additional information to your question.

---

> ***I did found my answer from another source***

Well, there are several options:

1. Mark your question as a duplicate, if the source was from Stack Overflow
2. Answer yourself, linking and rephrasing the source, how it answered your question
3. As long the answer isn't upvoted, delete your question

Comment: I would be very careful with "delete your question" option - depending on the Q/A pair there is reasonable chance that it actually useful (despite the fact OP could not understand answer yet). Consider it as an option if  question got downvotes/unclear what you are asking comments, otherwise keeping question with answer is better option.

Comment: Deleting your question after someone spent time and effort to answer is is in very poor taste.

Answer (score 13):

The checkmark is there to indicate that the answer is satisfactory to you and answered your question. In this case, it did not. Don't check it. If it doesn't help you, I wouldn't up vote it either. It's up to you, your votes are yours to use how you wish.

If it *is* a bad answer, you may be encouraging the author to continue writing bad answers.

Instead, consider using a comment asking for some clarification if you think the answer's author is on the right track. If it gets refined into an answer that helps you, then mark it as the answer.

> I did found my answer from another source

If you did find your answer, then you can always [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).